# Bing Search API seemingly ignoring $top value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, azure, bing-api

I'm using Bing Search API (Azure) to retrieve a list of newsheadlines using javascript/json. It's working but for some reason ignoring the $top (count) value, and giving me the default/maximum (15) number of results regardless of what I put there.

The call is:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?$format=JSON&Query=%27MyQuery%27&Sources=%27news%27&Market=%27en-US%27&Adult=%27Off%27&$top=5&$skip=0
```

I could limit it using the code on my page, but that seems wasteful to me. I have a suspicion that it's something obvious that I'm missing..

Your help is appreciated.

Note: the actual line of code within $.ajax that i'm using is a proxy php script:

```
url: "scripts/bingapi.php?query=" + escape("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?$format=JSON&Query=%27MyQuery%27&Sources=%27news%27&Market=%27en-US%27&Adult=%27Off%27&$top=10&$skip=0"),
```

Could it be something related to 'escape'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to JavaScript's [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) not handling the dollar sign `$` character. I would suggest using [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) instead like so:

```
url: "scripts/bingapi.php?query=" + encodeURIComponent("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?$format=JSON&Query=%27MyQuery%27&Sources=%27news%27&Market=%27en-US%27&Adult=%27Off%27&$top=10&$skip=0"),
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you; i did try it but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Strangely enough though, when I examine the raw json it seems that $top=1 is being passed. No idea why. I'll look at it more closely; i might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From Bing Composite service operation documentation:

> Also note that the number of results returned with the OData reserved parameter $top refers to all data sources specified in the query except News. News will always return a fixed number of 15 news results when you use it in a composite query.

Taken from: [Schema Tabular Documentation for Bing Search API](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_SCHEMA_GUIDE.docx)